# Java Scheduling task

Tags: java, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I am developing a spring mvc project where a notification will send to user mobile.User will select a datetime at format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' from frontend and save it to the database.when system time reach that time a notification will be send to the user mobile .

I created scheduler like this

```
  @Component
  public class NotificationScheduler extends BaseService {


  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 300000)
  public void sendNotification() {

    Date currentDate = new Date();

    System.err.println("HHHHHHHHHKKKKKK");

    List<ImageInfo> listImageInfo = imageInfoDao.getImageOfParticularDate(currentDate);

 }
}
```

this is my dao function which run a wuery to database

```
  public List getImageOfParticularDate(Date date) {
    session = getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<ImageInfo> imageInfoList = session.createQuery("select img from ImageInfo img where img.publishedTime =:publishedTime  ").setParameter("publishedTime", date).list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return imageInfoList;
}
```

this code is checking repeatedly at 5 min interval whether system time equal to publish time.if it is equal then a notification will be sent.I used Date type in model and Date type column in database. I want to know my approach is right or wrong because i can not get desire output.

Comment: the date that you are using is accurate to milliseconds, probably you want to selected based upon a time range?

Comment: `session.getTransaction().commit();` - why ?

Comment: First of all, you don't need to create a transaction just for one `select` query. Second, you comparing dates exactly, whereas what you actually should do is compare times in range, like @ScaryWombat said.

Comment: i put this query "select img from ImageInfo img where img.publishedDate >:systemTime " but still not getting output. :systemTime is system time.in my database publishDate is saved as date time.select query returning always 0 row

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a debug mode? Change, your the time rate you use in order to not wait too much, but I think you could determine that yourself, could you?